# How to construct a full URL in django

Tags: django, url, satchmo

I need to get django to send an email which contains a URL like this

```
http://www.mysite.org/history/
```

Where 'history' is obtained like so:

```
history_url = urlresolvers.reverse('satchmo_order_history')
```

history_url is a parameter that I pass on to the function that sends the email, and it correctly produces '/history/'. But how do I get the first part? (http://www.mysite.org)

**Edit 1**

*Is there anything wrong or unportable about doing it like this?* :

```
history = urlresolvers.reverse('satchmo_order_history')
domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
history_url = 'http://' + domain + history
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to an [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) instance, you can use [`HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri(location)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri):

```
absolute_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(relative_uri)
```

In alternative, you can get it using the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites):

```
import urlparse
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
absolute_uri = urlparse.urljoin('http://{}'.format(domain), relative_uri)
```

---

**Re: Edit1**

I tend to use [`urlparse.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin), because it's in the standard library and it's technically the most Pythonic way to combine URIs, but I think that your approach is fine too.

Comment: foo = urlparse.urljoin('http://', format(domain)) gives http:///mysite.org and urlparse.urljoin(foo, history) then gives http:///history/ What am I missing here? Also what is format() doing, and what is the {} for?

Comment: @user1294974 You can't use `urlparse.urljoin` to join `'http://'` and your domain, because they are partial uri fragments and it doesn't work. You have to concatenate the two strings. I'm using `str.format` for that (`{}` is a placeholder), but it requires Python 2.7. If it doesn't work you can try with `'http://{0}.format(domain)'` (Python 2.6), or `'http://%s' % domain` or even `'http://' + domain` like you are already doing.